# leaflet.js map.on('click', function... not working for me

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to record the latlng of a click on a Leaflet.js map. I plan on recording this to a database, but for the moment I just want to see evidence of the click location being recorded. I'm just trying to activate  an alert that prints the latlng as per the leaflet docs.

There's some additional stuff in this code which is just producing custom markers but that's fine right now.

If someone can point out where I'm going wrong with getting the simple alert down the bottom working I would appreciate it.

```
window.onload = function() {

var energyIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '../scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon-green.png',
    iconRetinaUrl: '../scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon-green-@2x.png',
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [25, 41],
    popupAnchor: [-12, -38],
    shadowUrl: '../scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png',
    shadowRetinaUrl: '../scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow-@2x.png',
    shadowSize: [41, 41],
    shadowAnchor: [25, 41]
});

var foodIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '../scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon.png',
    iconRetinaUrl: '../scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon--@2x.png',
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [25, 41],
    popupAnchor: [-12, -38],
    shadowUrl: '../scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png',
    shadowRetinaUrl: '../scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow-@2x.png',
    shadowSize: [41, 41],
    shadowAnchor: [25, 41]
});

var tourismIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '../scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon-red.png',
    iconRetinaUrl: '../scripts/leaflet/images/marker-icon-red-@2x.png',
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [25, 41],
    popupAnchor: [-12, -38],
    shadowUrl: '../scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png',
    shadowRetinaUrl: '../scripts/leaflet/images/marker-shadow-@2x.png',
    shadowSize: [41, 41],
    shadowAnchor: [25, 41]
});

var map = new L.Map('map', {
    zoom: 12, 
    center: new L.latLng(data[data.length -1].loc) //set center from first location
}); 

map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')); //base layer

var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();  //layer contain searched elements
map.addLayer(markersLayer);

// ===== populate map with markers from sample data and give it a different icon depending on its 'type'

for(i in data) {
    var title = data[i].title,  // value searched
        loc = data[i].loc,      // position found
        type = data[i].type;    // type
        title = data[i].title   // title

    if (data[i].type == "energy") {
        var marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title, icon: energyIcon});
    } else if (data[i].type == "food") {
        var marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title, icon: foodIcon} );
    } else if (data[i].type == "tourism") {
        var marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title, icon: tourismIcon} );
    }
    marker.bindPopup('Hello. I\'m ' + title + '. This is a place of type "'+ type + '" and is number ' + i + ' in this view.');
    markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
}

// ===== inizialize search control
map.addControl( new L.Control.Search({
    wrapper: 'findbox',
    layer: markersLayer,
    initial: false,
    collapsed: false
}) );

map.on('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.latlng); // e is an event object (MouseEvent in this case)
});
```

}

Comment: do you see any error in console when you click on map?

Comment: There's this;  'Cannot read property 'style' of null' for leaflet-search.min.js but I dont know if its relevant or stopping other stuff?

Comment: comment the `map.addControl()` function above the `click` function and then try.

Comment: It works with that commented out! Thanks. Any idea why that's causing a problem?

Comment: It looks like the search control had not been added properly, it may need some parameters which you are passing with null values, that is creating problem, for example check if 'findbox' exist etc

Comment: ahhh. Gotcha. There is a 'findbox' on another page, but not that one. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how to mark your comment as an answer. But if I can i will.

Comment: I've added my comment as map, you can mark it as answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `map.addControl()` is creating problem.

Comment out this function and then run your code. Hope it'd work